# Use of Image Compression

Tags: product-images, optimization

We have almost **300 products** on our site. For each product, we have created the **images**. Let say, the average size of images for one product is **4MB**. But as far as I understand, **cache serves the Storefront images** and the cache images are less in size compared to the original image size. In this case, can I directly upload the created images without using any compression? or is it good to use a compression tool to compress the images before uploading them to site?

Looking forward to your help.